Manga/Manhwa/Manhua where the a girl was reincarnated as a princess and wants to live her limited life peacefully
There was a cancer patient girl who was reincarnated as a baby princess with a hourglass tattoo in hand which means she will die in 21 years or so. She was a neglected princess of a powerful king of sword in the story the girl read but after she reincarnated she tried to change her fate by making different choices and ends up being the first child to learn magic in a sword lineage family and have very powerful magic. Also her magic teacher is main antagonist/villainess.
She started talking since baby and the family thought she has a talent for magic mage and as story progresses even her father started liking her. She said that she wants to live her remaining life peacefully with her family and wants to save them from the villainess. And even the title is like "wants to spend the rest of my life peacefully" but I can't find it.

Is this I Was Just Having Fun With the Time Limit...?

In my previous life, I had a limited time, but I reincarnated as someone with limited time again! Although this time too my life is limited, I got a life that lasts for 21 years. Even if I feel constrained, even breathing makes me happy! The family love I feel for the first time, and my mother asking me to grow up healthy. This life is a gift to me.


A Korean woman who'd fought cancer for most of her life dies and is reborn within a novel she'd read as Isabelle Bilotian, a baby princess in a family of swordsmen. She has a birthmark shaped like an hourglass on her right forearm, indicating that she'll die at the age of 21, and is able to speak when she's a few months old. As a girl, she isn't allowed to study swordsmanship like her father and brothers, but in chapter 7, a mage named Karin, who is also the villainess of the novel, is brought in to teach her magic.



